# User Session ID Limitations?

Tags: rest-api

I know we can grab the user's session ID in apex by using UserInfo.getSessionID() but what limitations are there as to what rest endpoints it can use and also is there any way for me externally to verify the token as to whether it is a valid token and the username/userid of the token.

Answer (score 0):

The Session ID is limited to whatever the parent session is limited to. For example, using the REST API, you'd have access to whatever APIs are within the `scope` of the OAuth session that was authorized, while in Lightning, you'd be limited to just the `UI API` methods, as the Lightning Session ID doesn't include REST or SOAP API access.

Comment: is there any way to check what the scope of the Session ID is?

Comment: this is more so I can run tests and see what scopes I get from what.

Comment: @KarlLivesey the only properties in aware of are in the [Auth session](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) object. You do get to know what kind of session you're using, but not specific properties like the OAuth scope, which is only relevant for OAuth login flows. You have to basically call the API and see what response you get.